# Find the non-regular point of the KKT problem

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, nonlinear-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

> min $2x_1^2+2x_2^2+4x$
> s.t g-$x_1^2+x_2^2-4\leq0$
> h-$x_1^2+x_2^2-4x_1+3\leq0$
> solve with KKT

I've found that the KKT point are (1,0),(2,0) and I wanted to find the non-regular point where the gradients of $h,g$ are linearly dependent but I get the following :
$$a\nabla g+b\nabla h=a2x_1+b2x_1-4b=0,ax_2+bx_2=0$$
And if $a\neq-b$ $x_1=\frac{2b}{a+b},x_2=0$ can cause the gradients to be always 0 so I have infinite solutions. where am I wrong here?

Comment: You're interested in points where the constraints are active and the gradients of $g$ and $h$ are linearly dependent.  At any point where a constraint is inactive, the corresponding Lagrange multiplier must be 0.

Comment: so in my case  I look for the intersection of the circles and then plug the corresponding $x_1,x_2$ and then check if they are linearly dependent?